# Django admin doesn't list models object but the count show there is

Tags: django, python-2.7, admin

I have a simple model

```
class Professeurs(Metadata):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    biographie = models.TextField()
    #photo = models.ForeignKey(image_model,blank=True)
    photo = models.OneToOneField(Photo,primary_key=True,blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s  %s" % (self.nom, self.prenom)
```

which is registerd in the admin like that

```
class general(admin.ModelAdmin):
   class Media:
     js = ('/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', '/static/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js',)

class ProfesseursAdmin(general):
    list_display = ('prenom' , 'nom' )
    fields = ['prenom','nom', 'biographie','photo']

admin.site.register(Professeurs, ProfesseursAdmin)
```

In django admin section you can just click on your model to see all the instance you have created of this model. The problem is when i create some "professeur" they don't show up in the report of the professeur admin panel. But the count show "3" so it see there is some object. I can not understand why they dont show up

Here is a picture of the problem
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14828537/Chose/Admin%20django.PNG

Comment: What is the "general" you are using in you admin class?

Comment: it heritates from  admin.ModelAdmin

class general(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', '/static/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js',)

Comment: can you provide the full content of the "general" class ? Maybe there is something in there that causes the conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I did a migration and primary keys were changed because of this field
photo = models.OneToOneField(Photo,primary_key=True,blank=True). The `primary_key=True` was messing with the professeur.id